# Straight from the horse's mouth

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases

I want to use the phrase "Horse's Mouth" in one of the applications that I am creating to refer to a group that have the original story. In the same application, there is another group of people, who just reports/narrate the original story. What can be a good word/phrase to describe such a group of people?

Comment: Even though it's clearly an orifice that makes noises based on what the mouth does, and only after the input has been thoroughly digested, I don't suppose you'd go for "horse's ass"...

Comment: @Hellion: :D :D

Comment: @Hellion: "You heard it first straight from the horse's mouth. But for an encore, let's hear it from the horse's ass" <Thunderous applause>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue the analogy, I'd call them **parrots**.

One of its meanings is: [[dictionary.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parrot)]

> a person who sedulously echoes another's words

Which seems to fit.

You could also consider **ravens**, which serve as message carriers in many fantasy works.

Comment: I like Ravens. But now the problem is "Horse's mouth" doesn't seem to go with Ravens. Can you think of a good alternative for "Horse's Mouth" that could go with Ravens.

Comment: @TheWanderer: I thought about that. You could use Parrot's beak, or raven's foot (where the message was tied)

Comment: While we are at it, there is a third group of people whom I am calling "gossipers" as of now. But if there can be a common theme for ravens, horse's mouth and gossipers then that would be just awesome !!!

Comment: @TheWanderer: Grasping at straws here. Magpies, like ravens, are from the crow family. The sound magpies make is chatter, a term is also used to refer to digital communication. Does that help? Magpie's beak?

Comment: Well I think, as of now I will stick with just "horse's mouth", ravens and gossipers. Bad choice of words I know, but seems like my best bet.

Comment: @TheWanderer: It's not that bad. I recommend a subtitle in your sections. As in... Horses: _Hear straight from the horses' mouth_ ; Ravens: _The message carriers_ ; Magpies: _The chatter happens here_

Comment: And from the nursery; 'A little bird told me...'

Comment: @TusharRaj +1 ..

Answer (score 1):

The usual word is just *reporters*. They serve the same role in your application that news reporters do in the real world.

This is often called a *[secondhand](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/secondhand) report*, so if you want a flowery term analogous to *horse's mouth*, you could call the reporters the Second Handers.

Comment: nice suggestion